# Processing.js - Generating Game Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing.js

I am currently working on 2D game (using Processing.js), and am looking to upgrade the world data section. Currently, I have one array that draws all the buildings, rivers etc., through a function. The problem is, I don't want to be loading everything all the time. I want to break the arrays up into multiple "chunks" (similar to the way Minecraft structures its world saves).

Here is the general idea of what the array would look like:

```
var world = [
[ [/*Chunk 1, Row 1*/], [/*Chunk 2, Row 1*/], ]
[ [/*Chunk 1, Row 2*/], [/*Chunk 2, Row 2*/], ]
];
```

The only issue with doing this, is I'm not sure how to enable natural generation. Lets say the player is at Chunk 2, Row 2 and enters Chunk 1, Row 1. When they enter I would want to generate Chunk 0, Row 0, so they can continue exploring/moving in that direction. How can I structure my code in away that can handle this type of generation.

Side notes: "One Chunk" will be considered 400 by 400 pixels (the screen size). Also, the game is played from a ariel view, thus people can go in all directions.

Any feedback or input would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean terrain? If you are using Perlin noise you can use the coordinates to determine what to generate. And you will always want to maintain a 3X3 block generated tiles, displaying the middle tile. Noise values can be used in the same way that random values are used to generate different features like buildings etc. That way you could have a virtually infinite map. The other option is to maintain the set of data that represents each tile in your map. Based on your response to this comment I'll see if I can put together an answer and some examples for you when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: Hello #Nolo. Yes I do mean the terrain. I am unfamiliar with Perlin noise, I'll check it out on the weekend. I'd like for the map to be virtually infinite (rather then a maintained set, which is what I currently have). The biggest thing I really am wondering is the best way to structure the data in a array (or other system). Then once the structure is in place, how to load new "chunks" into the correct location without disturbing the current screen. I'll be investing more time this weekend into this, maybe I'll find away that works based off what I've gathered. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: [Here is something](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/gradient-test/6517850685636608), but it's a mess/broken.  I have to sleep then work tomorrow. :D  But I will fix it so you can see.  Let's continue conversation in T&T there.

Comment: I've start a conversation in the T&T.